# What is best way to implement a queue in c#(System.Collection.Queue has memory limitation)

Tags: c#, queue, out-of-memory

I'm working on a problem, which need to do BFS traversal on a really large graph. Let's say 1 vertex could has at most 2^32 edges connect to other vertex .
I tried use System.Collection.Queue, however I quick get a out of memory exception.

I also tried use FileStream to implement a Queue persist to file, however it is really slow.There is no method like RemoveFirstLine from file supported. In order to remove the first line, I have to RealAllLine, remove first line in memory object, and then write back to file.

I'd like to know if there is any existing 3rd party library implement such a Queue without worry about memory.

If no, what's best way to implement it in c#.
What's the best FileXXXX class can do the work.

Comment: If the exception that is stopping you from doing this is an `OutOfMemoryException` then you aren't going to be able to implement a queue this large without using the file system.

Comment: You will run into memory issue if you implement your own queue in whatever data structure in-app.

A few suggestions: 1) Use filesystem 2) Use external message queue, eg. Redis, AWS SQS, RabbitMQ etc

Comment: I do consider use File system to implement such a queue, the abstract interface is not too complex. Just Enqueue, Dequeue. However, I didn't find right .net class to do it efficiently. Please refer to above.

I haven't think about Redis, AWS SQS, RabbitMQ yet. I'm not sure if I need a async message queue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queues are hard to get right, but if you're dealing with super large data-sets you should definitely look at ensuring a) you keep it stored with permanent storage b) you ensure simultaneous access by multiple processes/threads can't result in corruption or duplication of work. I'd strongly recommend using a 3rd-party implementation unless you have some very specific requirements. I'd also add c) ensure you have some way of resuming processing even after critical failure (e.g. power outage, which could occur while one process is half-way through processing a message).
FWIW a fairly simple multi-process-safe implementation could use 1 file per queue message, and make use of exclusive read-lock access to ensure only one process can read a new file at any time (and delete the file instead of releasing the lock when done).

Comment: So far, I don't need to consider multi-process, because the BFS algorithm itself may not support multi-process/thread.
I do need to be careful about File Access conflict, because I need to do both read and write. Right now, I close the FileStream everytime to ensure consistence. Tried just do Flush() but it doesn't work. So I have to close the Stream.